# How to make a comparison of duplicate/same filename based on date and time using app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In here I am trying to make a comparison of files with **SAME NAME** but having **DIFFERENT FILE UPLOAD DATE and TIME**. Therefore, the comparison of the file will take place based on the file's upload date and time.

I manage to detect the filenames that is been uploaded more than one time from the a file list and mark them as **'duplicate'**. I also manage to fetch those **SAME FILE NAME WITH ITS TIME AND DATE** .

[image]

Picture below are the data that i fetch

[image]

1. Now, I would like to make **comparison from the fetched data** based on the **file's upload date and time.**
2. If there are **same file name** then **pick the latest file** based on the date and time.
3. At the same time, **if the file is latest file or not duplicated** it will be labelled as **NEW DATA** meanwhile if the **file is old** then it will be labelled as **OLD DATA** in COLUMN E.

Here is the example that i would like to have:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
// Find locations of all duplicates
function getIndexes(data, duplicates) {
var column = 2;
var indexes = [];
i = -1;
// Loop through duplicates to find their indexes
 for (var n = 0; n < duplicates.length; n++) {
 while ((i = data.indexOf(duplicates[n], i + 1)) != -1) {
  indexes.push(i);
   }
 }
 Logger.log(indexes);
 Comparedate(indexes);

// Highlight all instances of duplicate values
for (n = 0; n < indexes.length; n++) {
 sheet.getRange(indexes[n] + 1, column).setBackground("yellow");//to set a duplicate marker
  sheet.getRange(indexes[n] + 1,4).setValue("duplicate"); //to set a duplicate marker
   }
 }

function Comparedate(){  
for(var r=2; r<=getlast;){
var duplicate = sheet.getRange(r,4).getValues();  
var name = sheet.getRange(r,2).getValues(); 
if(duplicate == "duplicate" && name==name){
var createdate = sheet.getRange(r,3).getValues();
 Logger.log(name + " " + createdate); // to get all the duplicate/same data
    }
 r++;
}
}
```

This is the google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n_uxICfseYA-VEjs4zSq1hAWTtzsFddSg-w2oblEWyw/edit?usp=sharing

This is the app script code for full view:
https://script.google.com/d/1vuwCgqjrvRJGypOf85HN6H_TxlEJ46BboRZnFN_rjx-rfFjSoe3YF07x/edit?mid=ACjPJvEGQj75gJ0l4D51I4zrqH1DkEVU6jw11W4mj0twJKlVPUb1YXsG2AANEVXNTSsvU_yjKXWIFJ437Xb7kVkDTjQhmVZRxEXe2Nw_JYitpBFHOLN-kKFHj1vCJLogUKqTYnMOXXHP&uiv=2

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for replying. How can I use those two getDisplayValues() and indexOf() in the code above? Sorry i still couldnt get the clearer idea of it

Answer (score 0):

#### Find the most recent file for each file name

```
function latestfiles() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const fs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  let files = { pA: [] };
  fs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!~files.pA.indexOf(r[1])) {
      files[r[1]] = [];//create object whose properties are filenames each of which have an array of date strings
      files[r[1]].push(r[2]);
      files.pA.push(r[1]);
    } else {
      files[r[1]].push(r[2]);//sort on each new addition so that most recent file is the first in the array
      files[r[1]].sort((a, b) => {
        let tA = a.split(' - ');
        let da = tA[0].split(/[/]/g);//Splitting the date strings up in search of fullyear, month, date, hour, minute etc
        let ta = tA[1].split(/[: ]/g);
        let vA = new Date(parseInt(da[2]), parseInt(da[1]) - 1, parseInt(da[0]), parseInt(ta[0]), parseInt(ta[1]), parseInt(ta[2])).valueOf() + parseInt((ta[3] == "AM") ? 0 : 43200000);
        let tB = b.split(' - ');
        let db = tB[0].split(/[/]/g);
        let tb = tB[1].split(/[: ]/g);
        let vB = new Date(parseInt(db[2]), parseInt(db[1]) - 1, parseInt(db[0]), parseInt(tb[0]), parseInt(tb[1]), parseInt(tb[2])).valueOf() + parseInt((tb[3] == "AM") ? 0 : 43200000);
        return vB - vA;//descending order
      });
    }
  });
  let colde = fs.map((r, i) => 
    [(files[r[1]][0] == r[2]) ? '' : 'duplicate', (files[r[1]][0] == r[2]) ? 'NEW' : 'OLD']
  );
  sh.getRange(2, 4, colde.length, colde[0].length).setValues(colde);//outputting the result
}
```

| EXCEL FILE ID | File Name | File Upload Datetime | Marker | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18eAo74bx36Jhk3 | FILE A.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 09:21:40 AM | duplicate | OLD |
| uebn2pobEH7uIhDY | FILE B.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 09:21:39 AM | duplicate | OLD |
| 3ymnplwgDfDevv | FILE C.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 09:21:37 AM | duplicate | OLD |
| 1nKOLt-AOA_7fgXa_ | FILE D.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 09:21:32 AM | duplicate | OLD |
| s7fhyrqerbqrbqbqbq | FILE 1.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 16:37:41 PM |  | NEW |
| 1A6N2DHq8SO7 | FILE B.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 09:47:33 AM | duplicate | OLD |
| 1OHmTTJverbww | FILE C.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 09:47:53 AM |  | NEW |
| I9Mbrqrbqbrrbs7fhyvv | FILE 3.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 16:37:41 PM |  | NEW |
| IsdvdweFI9Ms7fhy | FILE 2.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 16:37:41 PM |  | NEW |
| 19lv8BKm11wgwwv | FILE A.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 09:48:47 AM |  | NEW |
| _SOy8eNGnlbwewv | FILE D.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 09:49:04 AM |  | NEW |
| O18AFI9Ms7fhy | FILE B.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 16:37:41 PM |  | NEW |
| IsdvdweFI9Ms7fhy | FILE Z.xlsx | 14/01/2022 - 16:37:41 PM |  | NEW |

That was actually kind of an interesting script

Comment: thanks @Cooper, Can i have a simple explanation on the lines of codes? Maybe you can _command_ on what does the short forms represents at the `sort` part and any other related words in the lines. I would like to understand your process of executing it from the codes above.

Comment: Added some comments